# int()use base problem ---- int("2",2) make an error

Tags: python-3.x

I know for int("a",b), b is the base
why I could not use

```
print(int("2",2))
```

Exception has occurred: ValueError
invalid literal for int() with base 2: '2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting in most programming languages is from 0.

Binary is a base 2 number system and the only valid numbers are 0 and 1.

The int function converts strings to numbers but does not convert from one base to another.

Since 2 is not a valid base 2 number, python does not know how to translate that.

If you want base 2 of the number 2 from the input string, you will need to do

```
print(bin(int(2)))
```

Comment: thanks I thought base 2 means I could use 2=1*2+0*2, use 10 to represent 2, do you know the formula to calculate? I am confused why  int("10", 2)=2.